# Simplest, cheapest way to set up SMTP server on Linux?

Tags: linux, email, smtp

In the past I have tried following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer) for setting up a mail server on Ubuntu (going with Postfix, Dovecot, and Squirrelmail) and have been unsuccessful. I seemed to have been doing everything right, but the mail was not going through.

Anyway, it's been a while, and I would like to start over from scratch. What is the simplest, cheapest (preferably free if I already have a domain name + server) way I can set up an SMTP server on Linux?

My end goal is to be able to send simple, short emails to my cell phone (from the command line) as reminders. That's all I really need.

Comment: Aparently your previous attempt was successful, except for a minor gllitch in the configuration: you did not specify the right domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

Then set up a gmail account and use that to send email with it. Works really easily. I've done this for seeing who's logged in to my minecraft server so my son can jump in when his friend goes on line: http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/07/20/scripting-for-fun/

Comment: I have not yet tried this, but it looks like it is exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you had errors like "relay access denied", then this indicates, that your e-mail provider needs some sort of authentication. That's nothing you can fix by using a different mailer.

You must configure the credentials for your mailer properly. My e-mail provider expects a user/password authentication.  For my configuration (exim), this is configured on one line in a file `/etc/exim4/passwd.client` separated by colons:

> mail-relay-host:user-name:password

You might also look over at https://serverfault.com/, https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/, see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1449/26493

Comment: You're right, this probably should have been posted on a more relevant forum. Sorry!

Comment: No problem, just a suggestion :-)